# How to prove #R + #P = #R

Tags: cardinals, integers

I have already started this. I redefined the Reals as the Reals minus the Positive Integers (to make the two sets disjoint) so that I could prove that #(R - P) + #P = #R. I know that to prove this I will have to prove that #(R - P) = #(R). I would have to define a bijection, f:(R-P) -> R. I am having trouble coming up with a formula that will map the (R-P) to R. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Wait, so you're trying to prove $\#(\Bbb R\backslash\Bbb P)+\#\Bbb P=\#\Bbb R$ with $\Bbb P:=\{x\in\Bbb Z|x>0\}$? Well, $\#(A\backslash B)+\#B=\#A$ works for any sets $A,\,B$ with $B\subseteq A$, so perhaps I've misunderstood; perhaps you're trying to prove something less trivial.

Comment: I am trying to prove #(reals) + #(positive integers) = #(reals) by defining a bijection f: (R-P) --> R. I'm really sorry if my question is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to biject $[0,1)$ with $(0,1)$?  You can then use the identity on $(-\infty,0)$ and map $[n,n+1)$ to $(n,n+1)$